# How can i set an object active when its already set to disabled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

This is my code I try to enable my already disabled `gameobject` so it shows on CollisionEnter

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class JumpMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject jumptutorialbox;
    private GameObject triggerjumptut;
    public AudioSource audioPlayer;
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Triggered Jump Tutorial");
            triggerjumptut = GameObject.Find("TriggerJumpTut");
            triggerjumptut.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            jumptutorialbox = GameObject.Find("TutorialJUMP");
            jumptutorialbox.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            audioPlayer.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to enable a disabled object on CollisionEnter but I get this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
JumpMessage.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collision) (at Assets/Scripts/JumpMessage.cs:19)
```

Comment: You could describe what problem in-game you are trying to resolve, but maybe you can change collider to trigger. Triggers on a disabled object can work and OnTriggerEnter can be invoked to enable disabled object with trigger.

Another option will be creating a Manager that will disable/enable another object freely, as other said.

Comment: And tell as which line is number 19

Answer (score 0):

Hey so in unity in order to set an inactive gameobject back to active your gonna have to set it active through another gameobject because if an object in the scene is inactive the code and scripts are never gonna run so create another script and put it on a new gameobject and make a bool or something and that's how you can set it back to active

Comment: Wdym add a bool or something? I now added a active GameObject and added the disabled GameObject inside of it

Comment: no that's not what I mean I meant create a new game object by itself and put a new script on it. With that new script attached to the new game object create a bool if you want and set the object active or inactive with your new script on the new game object. Do not make the disabled object a child.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Empty GameObject with the code, with this you can Enable and Disable the other GameObject by code without any problem. I like call this GameObjects with those codes that gestion other GameObject's behavior as Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Check if something is found when you are using GameObject.Find. Insted of this you can probably use public variable and set reference to object in inspector.